# Pivotagem no Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Olá, pessoal. Tenho uma tabela no pandas e gostaria de transformar os valores na coluna DE_ANALITO em colunas cujos valores seriam aquilo que está na coluna DE_RESULTADO.

```
+----+----------------------------------+--------------------+----------------+
|    | ID_PACIENTE                      | DE_ANALITO         | DE_RESULTADO   |
|----+----------------------------------+--------------------+----------------|
|  0 | 3487791F44C34B421C932DC8616A8437 | Fosfatase Alcalina | 106            |
|  1 | 3487791F44C34B421C932DC8616A8437 | Gama-GT            | 33             |
|  2 | 3487791F44C34B421C932DC8616A8437 | ALT (TGP)          | 51             |
|  3 | 3487791F44C34B421C932DC8616A8437 | DHL                | 530            |
|  4 | 3487791F44C34B421C932DC8616A8437 | Proteína C-Reativa | 1,84           |
+----+----------------------------------+--------------------+----------------+
```

Tentei:

```
exames.pivot(index="ID_PACIENTE", columns="DE_ANALITO", values="DE_RESULTADO")
```

Porém retorna o erro:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Na documentação do método pivot é dado como exemplo a pivotagem de uma tabela com o mesmo formato que a minha, com coluna index também com valores repetidos. Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado

Answer (score 1):

Veja se dessa forma funciona para você

```
df.pivot_table(index = 'ID_PACIENTE', columns = 'DE_ANALITO', values = 'DE_RESULTADO', aggfunc = ''.join).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis = 1)
```

ou

```
df.pivot(index = 'ID_PACIENTE', columns = 'DE_ANALITO', values = 'DE_RESULTADO').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis = 1)
```

Saída:

```
                         ID_PACIENTE    ALT(TGP)    DHL Fosfatase Alcalina  Gama-GT Proteína C-Reativa
0   3487791F44C34B421C932DC8616A8437    51          530               106        33   1,84
```

---

Sobre o erro

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Você precisa verificar a sua base de dados, pois existem valores duplicados e dessa forma precisa trata-los